# Xamarin Android Read File API>24

Tags: android, xamarin

I am trying to read file from internal storage : donwload folder but it does not read if the API level is greater than 24.

I granded permissions on both manifest & runtime and I check that the app has these permissions granded on all API Levels.

Manifest Entries

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Code :

```
string fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine("storage/emulated/0/Download/", "reservation.txt");

string content;
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileName))
        {
            content = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

//ALSO TRIED THE FOLLOWING:

```
var path = global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;

var fileName = Path.Combine(path.ToString(), "reservation.txt");
```

Comment: I see the request rationale and that the app has granded the permissions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @ChrisFotopoulos Have you reviewed the `logcat` output? (also different OEM devices use different paths, you can not hardcode a path that comes from outside of your app's sandbox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the problem was not **on path** or **on permissions** but on read routine where we were using **stream reader** and we changed to

**string line = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName);**

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to read file from internal storage

but in your codes you're reading from [External Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=windows).So if you access the 
download fold of external storage,you could do like this:

for **Private External Storage**:

```
var path = GetExternalFilesDir(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
string fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(path.ToString(), "reservation.txt");
```

it will give a path like:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/package name/files/Download/reservation.txt
```

for **Public External Storage**:

```
var path = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
string fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(path.ToString(), "reservation.txt");
```

it will give the path like:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Download/reservation.txt
```